# Sort an array of objects based on a field and form a string from the sorted array with mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Have a document as follows

```
"id": "6350eecd1584de9f148a6a00",
"index": 0,
"noOfComments": 0,
"value": [{fieldOne : "hello" }, {fieldTwo : "world"} ],
"sortOn": {
      "value": "",
      "dataType": "label",
      "isRequired": false,
      "_id": "63649626b531d2442a97cfff",
      "lastEditTime": "2022-11-06T13:37:52.636Z",
      "detailedValue": [
        {
          "value": "label5",
          "_id": "6367b8b0f467747061155886",
          "color": "#FFB6FD",
          "status": -1
        },
        {
          "value": "label2",
          "_id": "6367b8b0f467747061155887",
          "color": "#FFE8B6",
          "status": -1
        },
        {
          "value": "label1",
          "_id": "6367b8b0f467747061155888",
          "color": "#CCDBF1",
          "status": -1
        },
        {
          "value": "label3",
          "_id": "6367b8b0f467747061155889",
          "color": "#DBB5FE",
          "status": -1
        },
        {
          "value": "label4",
          "_id": "6367b8b0f46774706115588a",
          "color": "#FFBAB5",
          "status": -1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Things I am trying to do

1. Sort the detailedValue array based on the field "value"
2. Form a string by concatenating the values of the sorted detailedValue
3. Set the field "sortOn" field as the string formed by concatenation
4. Project all exisiting fields

Expected Output

```
"id": "6350eecd1584de9f148a6a00",
"index": 0,
"noOfComments": 0,
"value": [{fieldOne : "hello" }, {fieldTwo : "world"} ],
"sortOn": "label1label2label3label4label5"
```

Query I tried to implement

```
{
    $unwind: {
      path: "$sortOn.detailedValue",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "sortOn.detailedValue.value": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "detailedValue": {
        $push: "$sortOn.detailedValue"
      },
      "value": {
        $first: "$value"
      },
      "index": {
        $first: "$index"
      },
      "noOfComments": {
        $first: "$noOfComments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      id: "$_id",
      value: "$value",
      index: 1,
      "detailedValue": 1,
      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project: {
  "sortOn.detailedValue": {
    $sortArray: {
      input: "$sortOn.detailedValue",
      sortBy: {
        value: 1
      }
    }
  },
  value: 1,
  index: 1,
  noOfComments: 1
}
},
{
"$project": {
  sortOn: {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$sortOn.detailedValue",
      "initialValue": "",
      "in": {
        "$concat": [
          "$$value",
          "$$this.value"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  value: 1,
  index: 1,
  noOfComments: 1
 }
}
])
```

1. Use $sortArray to sort the array ( MongoDB 5.2 and later )
2. Use $reduce to concat the values.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2X5lfpvmzLL)